# FreeMarker - Error reading included file "./common/header.txt":

Tags: java, runtime-error, freemarker

I try to use FreeMarker for creating `html file`.

But when I run program it throws error:

```
Error reading included file "./common/header.ftl":
Template "./common/header.ftl" not found.

The failing instruction:
==> #include "./common/header.ftl"  [in template "helloworld.ftl" at line 1, column 1]
```

***helloworld.ftl:***

```
<#include "./common/header.ftl"> 
<#if container??>
  <div ="${container}">
<#else>
  <div ="default">
</#if>

<ul>
<#list systems as system>
<li>${system_index + 1}.${system.getName()}</li>
</#list>
</ul>

<h1>${exampleObject.getName()}</h1>

</div>

<#include "./common/footer.ftl">
```

snippet of code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Configuration
    Writer file = null;
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

    try {
      // Set Directory for templates
      cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("templates"));
      // load template
      Template template = cfg.getTemplate("helloworld.ftl");

      // data-model
      Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      input.put("message", "vogella example");
      input.put("container", "test");

      // create list
      List<ValueExampleObject> systems = new ArrayList<ValueExampleObject>();
```

inner files `header.ftl` and `footer.ftl` are into `template/common` (into `template` exactly is helloworld.ftl and common).

**- Why this happen?

 - How to solve this trouble?**

Comment: Had you tried "/common/header.ftl"?

Comment: so what happens when you just use "common/header.ftl" ?

Comment: @Gimby Throws the same but with new data `Error reading included file "common/header.ftl":
Template "common/header.ftl" not found.`

Comment: @Andreas The same result and tried to move all files to template - `Error reading included file "header.ftl":` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like this. Double check if you have an oversight like `common` VS `commons` or `.txt` vs `.ftl`. Or, maybe you have two `templates` directories, and both have a `helloworld.ftl` but one of them has no `common` in it? I'm asking because your template directory (`new File("templates")`) is relative to the current working directory, which can be the source of lot of confusion. Never do that, it's very fragile. Use an absolute `File`.

**Unrelated to the question,** but the example contains sever ugly things:

This:

```
<#if container??>
  <div class="${container}">
<#else>
  <div class="default">
</#if>
```

could be simply written as:

```
 <div class="${container!'default'}">
```

Also, `${system.getName()}` and such (i.e., getter method calls) can be written as `${system.name}`.